# Can't update vars inside Angularjs Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

Anyone can help with this? Can't update var **ABCKey**. Execute setAuthenticatedAccount and console.log return correct value. After that, run getAuthenticatedAccount, and receive undefined.

```
angular.module('authentication.service', [
])

.factory('Authentication', ['$state', '$cookies', '$http', 'app', 'routes', 'cfCryptoHttpInterceptor',
    function($state, $cookies, $http, app, routes, cfCryptoHttpInterceptor) {

    var ABCKey;

    var setAuthenticatedAccount = function (account, tokenAuth) {
        var accountInfo = {'email': account.email, 'username': account.username, 'token': tokenAuth}
        var abc = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(account.abc);

        Authentication.setABCKey(abc);

        console.log(Authentication.showABCKey())

    }

    var getAuthenticatedAccount = function() {
        if(!$cookies.authenticatedAccount) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(Authentication.showABCKey())

    }


    var setABCKey = function(key) {
        ABCKey = key;
    };

    var showABCKey = function() {
        return ABCKey;
    };

    var Authentication = {
        setAuthenticatedAccount: setAuthenticatedAccount,
        getAuthenticatedAccount: getAuthenticatedAccount,
        setABCKey: setABCKey,
        showABCKey: showABCKey 
    };

    return Authentication;
}]);
```

Comment: The `getAuthenticatedAccount` function needs a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) after the [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Authentication` while you are calling your functions because it is creating object every time. And also set `var ABCKey=null` at the time of decelaration like this-

```
angular.module('authentication.service', [
])

.factory('Authentication', ['$state', '$cookies', '$http', 'app', 'routes', 'cfCryptoHttpInterceptor',
    function($state, $cookies, $http, app, routes, cfCryptoHttpInterceptor) {

    var ABCKey=null;

    var setAuthenticatedAccount = function (account, tokenAuth) {
        var accountInfo = {'email': account.email, 'username': account.username, 'token': tokenAuth}
        var abc = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(account.abc);

        setABCKey(abc);

        console.log(showABCKey())

    }

    var getAuthenticatedAccount = function() {
        if(!$cookies.authenticatedAccount) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(showABCKey())

    }


    var setABCKey = function(key) {
        ABCKey = key;
    };

    var showABCKey = function() {
        return ABCKey;
    };

    var Authentication = {
        setAuthenticatedAccount: setAuthenticatedAccount,
        getAuthenticatedAccount: getAuthenticatedAccount,
        setABCKey: setABCKey,
        showABCKey: showABCKey 
    };

    return Authentication;
}]);
```

Comment: This way, console.log returns "null"

Answer (score 0):

dont use var its single tone class you need to define ABCkey in this

var ABCKey;

try with this

```
this.ABCKey = '';
```

Comment: In service we can use this, not in factory.

Comment: Yes .this should be use in service but we can use in factory as well, check : https://codepen.io/sumit-jaiswal/pen/xrJLxE?editors=1111